# Carry the id of a row to modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that is being populated dynamically from the database, In it there is a button on whose click i wish to display a modal, as the work is done in bootstrap so its not difficult to create a modal.

```
<table id="report" class="table table-bordered" >
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>   
    <?
    $sql="SELECT * from `request` ";
    $result= mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {   
                    $requestid = $row['requestid']; 
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><? echo $requestid; ?> </td>
                        <td><div href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-drank mb-10" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Detail</div></td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>
              <?} 
        }
</table>
```

Table will look similar to this

[image]

Now the part where i am stuck is that i also wish to carry the requestid of the row whose corresponding detail button user has clicked to the modal, so that if user clicks on detail of first row, modal displays the data of first row, and when the user clicks on detail of second row, modal displays the data of second row and so on..

Code for modal is

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Details</h4>
                </div>
                    // wish to get the request id and once i have it i can use it to fetch data

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: your problem is not clear...what exactly do you need?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Adding this update on top because I feel this would be more elegant and easiest way.

No need of having **Step 1** and **Step 2** i.e. a `global variable` and `click event` for *`modal invoker`*. You can just have `shown.bs.modal` method and get the `sourceElement` i.e. element that invoked `modal`, and fetch `id` corresponding to that `row` as below:

```
$("#myModal2").on('shown.bs.modal',function(e){
    var sourceElement=e.relatedTarget;
    /*e.relatedTarget gives you which element invoked modal*/
    var id=$(sourceElement).closest('tr').find("td:first").text();
    /*using sourceElement you can easily fetch id
    alert(id);
})
```

<kbd>**[`Updated DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/x1qd2t5L/2/)**</kbd>

---

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/x1qd2t5L/1/)**

<strike>3 steps:</strike>

- Have a global variable to store `id`
- Click event to all `div` whose `data-target="#myModal"` to fetch clicked `row`'s id
- Make use of modal's `shown.bs.modal` to get `id` obtained during `click` event

**Step 1**

```
var id=0; /*a global variable*/
```

**Step 2**

```
$("div[data-target=#myModal2]").on('click',function(){
    id=$(this).closest('tr').find("td:first").text();
    /*get the closest tr of clicked div and find first td which has id value and store it in
    id variable*/
})
```

**Step 3**

```
$("#myModal2").on('shown.bs.modal',function(e){
    alert(id);
    /*since id is a global variable and it will get value as soon as click occurs
    Fetch the data with above id*/
})
```

Comment: k so i get the id, but how can i carry it inside the modal

Answer (score 0):

Add data-id="id of the row" in button

```
<button data-id="id of the row" class="btn btn-drank mb-10" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal2">Detail</button >
```

Put a form tag and input type hidden in that form.

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">                           
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <form >
                                <input type="hidden" id="id">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Then in script do it with event show.bs.modal

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myModal12').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);//Button which is clicked
            var clickedButtonId= button.data('Id');//Get id of the button
          // set id to the hidden input field in the form.         
           $("input #id").val(clickedButtonId);
    });
```

Comment: i tried your code, when i am trying to take the hidden input to backend its not getting displayed

Comment: Is it visible on the modal when you inspect it? You must give name to the input hidden type that will map it with back-end variable.

Comment: Have you put data-id="id of the row" ?? (id of row is your actual id of the row)

Comment: Okie i got now, change <div href="javascript:;" data-id="id of the row" class="btn btn-drank mb-10" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal2">Detail</div>   to button  like  <button  data-id="id of the row" class="btn btn-drank mb-10" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal2">Detail</button>

Comment: It should work now, change div to button which is clicking the modal

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener for `show.bs.modal` so you have a reference to the componet clicked by the user and to the modal, as stated in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target).

```
$('#myModal2').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var modal = $(this);
    var rowBtn = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var row = rowBtn.closest('tr');
    // Here you id for the clicked row
    var rowId = row.find('td:first').text();
    row.find('td').each(function(){
        // Here you can iterate between each row cell
        var cellCont = $(this).text();
        // e.g. use cellCont to create modal content
    });
    // Here you can update modal content
    // e.g. modal.find('.modal-body').html( your dynamic content );
});
```